# .matches in powershell not returning any results

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script that is based off of a cryptography script on [blog.commandlinekungfu.com](http://blog.commandlinekungfu.com/). Essentially I want to get the frequency of all of the letters in a text file. In the example, he uses Here-String to store the values, but I want to use Get-Content. Here's the breakdown.

This code works

```
PS c:\$foobar = @"
                  foo
                  bar
                "@
PS c:\$foobar | Select-String -AllMatches "[A-Z]").matches
```

It returns the approriate values. However, if I have a text file that contains exactly the same information, I get a null value returned.

```
PS c:\$text = Get-Content "foobar.txt"
PS c:\$text | Select-String -AllMatches "[A-Z]").matches
```

Returns nothing

Does anyone know why a Here-String works but not Get-Content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The here string is treated as one string, with get-content you pipe a collection of strings. You can pipe the filoe content to the Out-String cmdlet:

```
(get-content file.txt | out-string | Select-String -AllMatches "[A-Z]").matches
```